# How to use ARRAYFORMULA to count the nb of word for every row

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, countif, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I'm using google form and after submitting data, I want to count (number of word "OUI" ) for every row.
I tried the function: `=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(B$3:D3;"*OUI*"))` but it works only for the first row.

[image: Screen of spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the solution provided by player0, another way would be to use countif...

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A3:A),COUNTIF(if(B3:D="OUI", ROW(A3:A)),ROW(A3:A)),))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A), 
 MMULT(IFERROR(LEN(B3:D)/LEN(B3:D), 0), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B3:D3)^0)), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A), 
 MMULT(IFERROR(LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(B3:D, "OUI", "♦"), "♦"))/
               LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(B3:D, "OUI", "♦"), "♦")), 0), 
 TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B3:D3)^0)), ))
```

[image: 0]