# How to count partial matches by row using an arrayformula?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, sum, max, array-formulas

My question expands on what was asked here.  ([How to use ARRAYFORMULA to count the nb of word for every row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56237150/how-to-use-arrayformula-to-count-the-nb-of-word-for-every-row/56237712#56237712))

I want to count partial matches for each row.  I've tried using the * as a wildcard but I get big fat zeros returned.
This works if I only want to count exact matches of "NP".
={"NP Count";arrayformula(if(len(A3:A),COUNTIF(if(F3:G="NP",row(F3:F)),row(F3:F)),))} 
Columns B:D are hidden.

| ID# (A) | NP Count(E) | Date 1(F) | Date 2(G) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 | NP-PM | NP |
| 67890 | 0 | NP-PC |  |
| 24680 | 2 | NP | NP |

The NP count should be 2, 1, 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(N(REGEXMATCH(INDIRECT("C2:D"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))), "NP")), {1;1}))
```

[image]

Comment: That did the trick.  Not exactly sure what each of those do individually so I'll have to break it down eventually so I can apply it to other problems as needed.  Learning little by little.  Thanks.

Comment: @Charity if A2:A is not empty = TRUE (if its empty = FALSE). true/false = 1/0 so each ROW number from A2:A gets multplied by 1 or zero. MAX of it is row 4 multiplied by 1 = 4 so INDIRECT creates a range C2:D4. in this range we use regex to match "NP" (case sensitive). if there is a match output is TRUE otherwise FALSE. to convert true/false to 1/0 we use N() wrapping. then we use MMULT to sum all ones and zeros per each row. range C2:D4 equals to 2 columns so we transpose those "2" column as 2 rows and in each row we put 1 hance the {1;1} (coz MMULT works that way).

Comment: @Charity INDEX is used instead of ArrayFormula only because its shorter to type.